# Hide Apache Version, PHPVersion from website

Tags: php, apache, wamp, cs-cart

I have installed Wamp server on my Windows7 machine

I have a CS-Cart website running quite fine.
My only problem is that Wamp Server displays some "Server Configuration" info (Apache Version , PHP version, Loaded Extensions....) in big bold white font, that completely messes up my template.

How can I "hide" (disable) this info from displaying?

I have already searchedva bit and set  **ServerSignature** to Off with no luck...

[image]

Comment: If you put the correct settings in the correct files and restarted everything, the information won't be sent through headers or appear in system files anymore. If it still appears, it's explicitly printed through your software / scripts.

Comment: I will check. The software is CS-Cart, all its files have been downloaded via FTP from production site which doesn't show anything at all of course...

Answer (score 1):

Open httpd.conf file using text editor and add /modify the directive as follows:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

Open php.ini file using text editor and modify the line containing “expose_php = On” and set it to Off:

```
expose_php = Off
```

Comment: expose_php is already set to Off...nothing changes

could it be some CS-Cart related feature?

Comment: This will hide the version from showing up in HTTP response headers only. If it's showing up in your HTML webpage, then check your code.

Comment: The php pages have been taken from the production website (a CS-Cart) and directly copied on Wamp locally...production website is OK and running well...
I can't understand where those info come from...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ServerTokens` directive. Changing this to "Prod" will turn off all but the fact you're using Apache.

Comment: I had already set to ProductOnly, changing it to "Prod" has no effect (yes, I have restarted Apache on WAMP) ;-)